# Proper way to echo JSON in php

Tags: php, json

Hi i am looking for a proper way to echo json in my php api, currently this is my echo code

I am getting this from a different class

```
echo '{"accountStatus":{';
echo '"create_status_code": "400",';
echo '"message": "Unable to create user."';
echo '}}';
```

I am getting this from a different class

```
echo '{';
echo '"status_code": "em200",';
echo '"message": "email duplicate"';
echo '}';
```

At the end this is what i am getting which is not valid JSON

```
{ 
"status_code":"em200",
"message":"email duplicate"
}{  
"accountStatus":{  
"create_status_code":"400",
"message":"Unable to create user."
}
}
```

So please how do i echo it properly?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php

Comment: That's because you're echoing invalid json. You may want to look at php documentation on json serialization.

Comment: use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 14):

Don't forget to set the header if you want your browser to properly see it as json:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode(array(
    "age" => 4,
    "name" => "baby",
));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can create the messages as an array, you can use json_encode to get a valid JSON-output:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    "accountStatus" => array(
        "create_status_code" => "400",
        "message" => "Unable to create user",
    ),
    "status_code" => "em200",
    "message" => "email duplicate",
));
```

Answer (score 1):

For this to work properly, you need proper JSON input or at least convert it to it. If you can change the way the classes output the JSON, make it output it as this:

### Using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

#### First Class

```
echo '{"accountStatus":{';
echo '"create_status_code": "400",';
echo '"message": "Unable to create user."';
echo '}}';
```

Should be a JSON Object:

```
/* ClassOneOutput */
return json_decode('{
    "accountStatus": {
        "create_status_code": "400",
        "message": "Unable to create user."
    }
}', true);
```

#### Second Class

```
echo '{';
echo '"status_code": "em200",';
echo '"message": "email duplicate"';
echo '}';
```

Should be a JSON Object:

```
/* ClassTwoOutput */
return json_decode('{
    "status_code": "em200",
    "message": "email duplicate"
}', true);
```

#### Combining them:

```
/* Main script fetches class output */
$classTwoOutput = classTwo();
$classOneOutput = classOne();

$classOutput = array($classOneOutput, $classTwoOutput);

echo json_encode($classOutput, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely bad idea. Just use `jsonSerialize`;

```
echo json_encode(new StringValue('Hello!'), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Referenced [link](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php)