# Why I can't get file content using file_get_contents for this site in php

Tags: php, json, localhost, liveserver

Peace be upon you.
I just developed a free PHP tool that extracts YouTube video details of all public videos in json format. It works perfectly with local server and live server. But the problem is if I get the content using the file_get_contents in php with the local server site it works perfectly but if I try to get the content with the live server it don't work.

[image: Screenshot of Result]

Script which i used to get content:

```
<?php require '../3lsp/3l_smart_php.php';?>
<h1>Using Local Server</h1>

<?php
$x = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://localhost/ytinfo/?id=0WO5uUWHz3o'));
echo '<b style="color:red">Title: </b>'.$x->title.'<hr>';
echo '<b style="color:red">Author: </b>'.$x->author.'<hr>';
echo '<b style="color:red">Quality: </b>'.$x->quality.'<hr>';
echo '<b style="color:red">Views: </b>'.$x->views.'<hr>';
echo '<b style="color:red">Length: </b>'.format_time($x->lengthSeconds).'<hr>';
echo '<b style="color:red">Description: </b>'.$x->shortDescription.'<hr>';
?>

<h1>Using Live Server</h1>

<?php
$y = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://ytinfo.ezyro.com/?id=0WO5uUWHz3o'));
echo '<b style="color:red">Title: </b>'.$y->title.'<hr>';
echo '<b style="color:red">Author: </b>'.$y->author.'<hr>';
echo '<b style="color:red">Quality: </b>'.$y->quality.'<hr>';
echo '<b style="color:red">Views: </b>'.$y->views.'<hr>';
echo '<b style="color:red">Length: </b>'.format_time($y->lengthSeconds).'<hr>';
echo '<b style="color:red">Description: </b>'.$y->shortDescription.'<hr>';
?>
```

How to Solve?

Comment: [What do you mean "It doesn't work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)
. Have you checked (for example) the HTTP response code you receive from the remote server (if any), firewall rules, proxy setup, or anything else network-related which might be relevant? In other words, what debugging have you done? Just showing us some code which works in one context but not in another usually does not reveal any problems to us. We need information resulting from the actual code execution and your efforts to investigate the environment - we cannot see it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620124/http-requests-with-file-get-contents-getting-the-response-code - start with this to get the http response

Comment: That URL uses JavaScript. Since `file_get_contents()` doesn't run JS, it returns an HTML page, not the JSON result.

Comment: You can see this if you do `$content = file_get_contents('http://ytinfo.ezyro.com/?id=0WO5uUWHz3o'); echo htmlentities($content);`

Comment: You'll see this message: `This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support`

Comment: @Barmar when I visited http://ytinfo.ezyro.com/?id=0WO5uUWHz3o in my browser it returned raw JSON

Comment: @ADyson The JS sets a cookie, then reloads the URL. The server is presumably checking the cookie to determine whether JS is enabled.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, I had already run it once when I reported that. So I guess I already had the cookie, therefore it just returned the JSON result immediately.

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents('http://ytinfo.ezyro.com/?id=0WO5uUWHz3o')` is returning the following HTML:

```
<html>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js"></script>
  <script>
    function toNumbers(d) {
      var e = [];
      d.replace(/(..)/g, function(d) {
        e.push(parseInt(d, 16))
      });
      return e
    }

    function toHex() {
      for (var d = [], d = 1 == arguments.length && arguments[0].constructor == Array ? arguments[0] : arguments, e = "", f = 0; f < d.length; f++) e += (16 > d[f] ? "0" : "") + d[f].toString(16);
      return e.toLowerCase()
    }
    var a = toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),
      b = toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),
      c = toNumbers("d72fb33abc28df4430f7b7643e8aeda2");
    document.cookie = "__test=" + toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c, 2, a, b)) + "; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
    location.href = "http://ytinfo.ezyro.com/?id=0WO5uUWHz3o&i=1";
  </script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body>

</html>
```

As you can see, it's creating a cookie with an encrypted value, then reloading the page with the additional `i=1` parameter. The server is presumably checking for that that cookie value, and only returns the JSON when it finds it.

The value of the cookie should be `49262d78c44eed05b1683afbc9b5364f`, you can add that in your `file_get_contents()`.

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'header' => "Cookie: __test=49262d78c44eed05b1683afbc9b5364f\r\n"
    ]
]);
$y = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://ytinfo.ezyro.com/?id=0WO5uUWHz3o&i=1', false, $context));
```

Comment: Presumably that value is there to prevent automated scraping such as this, and will change frequently, if not on every request.

Comment: @miken32 I was expecting that, but it hasn't changed in more than 15 minutes so far.

Comment: If it does change, it should be possible to write PHP code that extracts the `a`, `b`, and `c` strings from the script and calculates the cookie from it.

Comment: Your code is not working because the cookies have been updated.

Comment: Your code is not working because the cookies have been updated. I am not an expert in php. The first question is why this is happening on Levi's server. The second is to specify a code that will retrieve the latest cookie and run the code correctly. I would be grateful if you could provide me with the best code to do this.

Answer (score -2):

It will work like this, create a variable with the URL, use the URL as an argument to the file_get_contents() function, then use json_decode() function to decode JSON string to PHP object, which will display the content perfectly.
ALSO make sure you enable allow_url_fopen to use the file_get_contents() function if it isn't already active. We can enable it by setting phpini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1) in the php.ini file.

```
<h1>Using Live Server</h1>

<?php
$url = 'http://ytinfo.ezyro.com/?id=0WO5uUWHz3o';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$y = json_decode($json);
echo '<b style="color:red">Title: </b>'.$y->title.'<hr>';
echo '<b style="color:red">Author: </b>'.$y->author.'<hr>';
echo '<b style="color:red">Quality: </b>'.$y->quality.'<hr>';
echo '<b style="color:red">Views: </b>'.$y->views.'<hr>';
echo '<b style="color:red">Length: </b>'.format_time($y->lengthSeconds).'<hr>';
echo '<b style="color:red">Description: </b>'.$y->shortDescription.'<hr>';
?>
```

Comment: Using separate variables for the arguments won't make any difference. Did you try this?

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` must be enabled since he's using a URL for `localhost`.

Comment: @Barmar I used seperate variables for the arguments to make it neater imo, and to see if something was possibly typed incorrectly. It's automatic now haha.  and I figured id let him know about the allow_url_fopen setting in case he wasn't aware. After looking at the persons page, it's using JS and JSON?

Comment: `to make it neater`...yeah that's fine, but it's functionally identical so it won't actually fix anything. If you're proposing only cosmetic changes to the code, that should be clear in your description.

Comment: `it's using JS and JSON`...yes, as Barmar pointed out, it downloads JS first, so file_get_contents can't work with it. Seems like it's basically a defence against this kind of scraping.

Comment: @ADyson But it's an easily defeated defense, I reverse-engineered it in minutes.

Comment: @ADyson my apologies. Could he possibly use jsonSerialize? I'd hate for the guy to have to redo his code just for it to work properly. or use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299823/proper-way-to-echo-json-in-php

Comment: @KenDeadmausMitchell don't think that jsonserializeable interface (assuming that's what you mean) would help, since we're dealing with a HTML string from the server, not a PHP class